# Administrator is returning null but why?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the following test.

```
[TestFixture]
    public class AdministratorRepositoryTests
    {
        private IAdministrateurRepository repository;

        public static IAdministrateurRepository MockAdministrateurRepository(params Administrateur[] items)
        {
            var mockRepos = new Mock<IAdministrateurRepository>();
            mockRepos.Setup(x => x.Select()).Returns(items.AsQueryable());
            return (IAdministrateurRepository)mockRepos.Object;
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void SetupContext()
        {
            Guid gId1 = new Guid("a05fd3de-9ae4-4b0b-b560-fd96678d3019");
            Administrateur a1 = new Administrateur(gId1);

            Guid gId2 = new Guid("e0724d12-d856-4677-89aa-d12611c15a4c");
            Administrateur a2 = new Administrateur(gId2);

            Guid gId3 = new Guid("30a69d49-84e5-42fc-a643-9e42c1350aa8");
            Administrateur a3 = new Administrateur(gId3);

            Guid gId4 = new Guid("b6444711-baee-4da6-87a8-a839c438bdff");
            Administrateur a4 = new Administrateur(gId4);

            Guid gId5 = new Guid("9d805acd-9d59-44ac-892c-438b189bbf94");
            Administrateur a5 = new Administrateur(gId5);

            repository = MockAdministrateurRepository(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5);

        }

        [Test]
        public void peut_recuperer_un_administrateur_dun_repository_par_son_id()
        {
            Guid monGuid = new Guid("a05fd3de-9ae4-4b0b-b560-fd96678d3019");

            var administrateur = repository.SelectById(monGuid);

            administrateur.ShouldNotBeNull();
            administrateur.Id.ShouldEqual(monGuid);
        }
    }
```

I am struggle to understand WHY the administrateur is returning NULL.

```
var administrateur = repository.SelectById(monGuid);
```

I even did a count test on the repository and it has 5 items.

Any help ?

Comment: It looks like your mocking utility is not behaving like you expect.  Please add a tag to your for said Mocking Utility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see this problem a lot -- you're fundamentally misunderstanding what the purpose of mocking/faking/stubbing is.  That is, you're writing a test for a fake implementation and, as a result, **the test is useless**.  Think about it -- what is your test trying to prove?  You're trying to verify that you can get results out of a repository, but:

```
// this is a mock/fake/stub/whatever, it's NOT the real class
var repository = new Mock<IAdministrateurRepository>(); 

// and so.. what is the point in this when your 
// IAministratorRepository is not the production version?
var administrateur = repository.SelectById(monGuid);

// The repository is meant to be the focus of the test, 
// yet you're not testing a result of using a real class
administrateur.ShouldNotBeNull();
administrateur.Id.ShouldEqual(monGuid);
```

The above line is pulling data out of your repository, but the repository is not a real implementation.  It's not production code.   If so, then why do you then assert on the `Administrator` object that is pulled out of the fake repository?  The behaviour you're testing is the search by ID functionality, yet it is defined inside your test fixture! You've created a stubbed/fake implementation and then tested it -- nothing more.  Mocks/Stubs/Fakes are meant to have expectations or provide canned results to drive the testing of real types  (read: types used in production).  Testing the mock itself achieves nothing.

Before you write any test code, you should ask yourself **what is the purpose of this test?**  If you can't answer that question, resolve it before you write the test code.  If you were to actually be testing your `AdministratorRepository`, you would instantiate the production code version of the repository and then manipulate it, then assert on some aspect of its behaviour.

This [blog post](http://defragdev.com/blog/?m=200908) might help you.  I would advocate ditching mocking frameworks and using state-based testing until you are totally clear on where mocking/stubbing fits in, as it's easy to become confused by interaction-based testing.

*edit -- **OK, here's (roughly) what your code should look like**
Ignore the implementation details, just focus on the roles of each type and notice that it's simple as can be.

```
// interface
public interface IAdministratorRepository
{
    Administrator SelectById(Guid _id);
    void Add(Administrator _admin);
}

// minimal implementation of admin.  
public class Administrator
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Administrator(Guid _id)
    {
        Id = _id;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// For argument's sakes, this is the class under test.  
/// It's not a mock/fake/stub/whatever; it's the real deal!
/// </summary>
public class RealAdministratorRepository : IAdministratorRepository
{
    private Dictionary<Guid, Administrator> m_items = new Dictionary<Guid, Administrator>();

    public Administrator SelectById(Guid _id)
    {
        // no error handling here; keeping it simple
        if(m_items.ContainsKey(_id))
            return m_items[_id];

        return null;
    }

    public void Add(Administrator _admin)
    {
        // No error handling for brevity's sakes
        m_items.Add(_admin.Id, _admin);
    }
}

// now, here's a very, very simple happy path test for SelectById using
// the real implementation of AdministratorRepository
[TestFixture]
public class AdministratorRepositoryTests
{
    private const string AdminId = "a05fd3de-9ae4-4b0b-b560-fd96678d3019";
    private IAdministratorRepository m_repository;

    [SetUp]
    public void PerTestSetUp()
    {
        // no mocks/stubs required.  m_repository is a RealAdministratorRepository
        // because that's our production class and that's what we want to test!
        m_repository = new RealAdministratorRepository();
        m_repository.Add(new Administrator(new Guid(AdminId)));
    }

    [Test]
    public void SelectById_WithItemsInRepository_ReturnsCorrectItems()
    {
        // ignore the fact that I'm repeating the same string 3 times; brevity again
        var item = m_repository.SelectById(new Guid(AdminId));

        Assert.That(item, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(item.Id, Is.EqualTo(new Guid(AdminId)));
    }
}
```

Notice that I am not using a mocking framework because I don't need to.  The production code doesn't have any problematic dependencies that require mocking/stubbing/faking.

Comment: Great explanation of what the purpose of test doubles is.

Comment: Well i actually configure the mock to return a list of contained items so that should work otherwise why it tell me there 5 items in it?

Comment: Rushino: Yes, it does have 5 items, but the thing that has 5 items is the fake repository you have created using "new Mock<IAdministrateurRepository>();".  The Mock repository won't be used in production code, so what value do you get out of testing it?

Comment: I've added some more information about what your tests probably should look like

Answer (score 4):

Mocking and faking are two different concepts.  You seem to think that you're setting up a repository by adding data to it and expecting that data to be there.  That's how a *fake* repository works; it's like the real repository but much simpler and contains only the data you set it up with.  A *mock* repository on the other hand doesn't actually contain the data, but contains a set of responses to method calls with particular signatures.  You set up a response to the `Select()` call with no parameters, but you're actually invoking the `SelectById()` call with a particular parameter.  Because there's no response set up for this call beforehand, it returns a null result, i.e., the default when no matching call can be found.

Comment: It seem its a mock configured to return items from the params list ? I mean it do exactly what a mock should do. Make it return something you actually want to return.

Comment: Rushino: Mocks aren't stubs.  You're treating a mock like a stub and also testing the wrong thing.  Read my post then read these links: http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html & http://www.osherove.com/blog/2007/9/16/mocks-and-stubs-the-difference-is-in-the-flow-of-information.html

Answer (score 2):

You set up `Select` but uses `SelectById` in the test.

Comment: See the answer by Mark Simpson. You have a bigger problem - Your test does actually not test anything but the Moq-framework!

Answer (score 2):

You have to setup the mock repository in your `MockAdministrateurRepository` method to return the desired Administarateur.

```
mockRepos
    .Setup(x => x.SelectById(new Guid("a05fd3de-9ae4-4b0b-b560-fd96678d3019")))
    .Returns(a1);
```

Comment: You're correct, but I think the answer misses a larger problem with the approach used.

Comment: @Mark Yes, your answer explains that very well, that's why I voted it up ;-)

Comment: @Rushino, no you just setup the `Select` method, not the `SelectById` method. Mocks don't do anything by themselves, read Mark's answer to be enlightened ;)